# Dimension of affine hull of a convex set.

Tags: convex-analysis, affine-geometry

I am trying to prove the following.

$C$ is a nonempty convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that $\operatorname{dim}(\operatorname{aff}(C))$ is the maximum of the dimensions of the simplexes contained in $C$.

Where $\operatorname{dim}(\operatorname{aff}(C))$ refers to the dimension of the affine hull of the convex set C. I know that $\operatorname{dim}(\operatorname{aff}(C))$ = $\operatorname{dim}(C)$ but couldn't figure out how to form the proof. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @CyclotomicField

Maximum dimensions of simplices in C is K and dim(aff($C$)) $\geq k$. Tried S is a simplex. Its affine hull is equal to the span of the vectors $v_1 - v_0, v_2 - v_0, \ldots, v_k - v_0$, where $v_0, v_1, \ldots, v_k$ are the vertices of $S$ these vectors are linearly independent hence the dim(aff($C$)) $\geq k$ 

Conversely continued with dim(aff($C$)) $\leq k$ and wanted to make proof by contradiction however couldn't do it yet. Now I believe by showing those to I can find the equality.